# What is SAObjects.framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I've added [SACalendar](https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar) custom classes to my Xcode project and now when I run the app I get this log:

> objc[3230]: Class SACalendar is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects and /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/MyApp. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

What is such `SAObjects.framework`? Would this conflict cause actually a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, it is a private framework (meaning that it contains stuff that does not have a public API).  I think this one started shipping with iOS7.

IMO, Apple should do a better job naming their private classes, and prefix them with an underscore or something, but they don't.  That framework even has classes with no specific prefix (like AceObject).

Since ObjectiveC does not have namespace support, you can (and will) get name collisions.  All you can do is rename your classes that clash with system frameworks... and hope your prefix of choice is not chosen by some other framework shipped with the system.

I would advise you to rename your SACalendar class, and any other classes that cause a conflict.

If you want to know the contents of that framework, just load it and use the objc runtime to discover its properties... or use one of the many tools already available (like [this one](https://github.com/nst/RuntimeBrowser/)).

Comment: With namespace support you would have collisions of namespaces. There are rules for naming, but they are not respected.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Indeed, but it's much easier to rename a namespace.  Also, in languages with namespace support, it is common for one namespace to be used to house API, and then subnamespaces are nested.  If ObjC had namespaces, apple could claim a single top-level namespace, and then everything else could be in namespaces under there.  This would mean that there were only one single namespace that their stuff lived under.

Comment: You can have "subnamespaces" as well with conventions. Simply take a top-level prefix and add a second level prefix and so on. There would really be no problem, if developers would respect the naming conventions.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I agree... and you are preaching to the choir... my prefix of choice is WJH... but the reason is that Apple foolishly took the "easy" prefixes, and left the "difficult" ones to the masses.  If they had reserved something other than what they did for themselves, then it would allow developers more "freedom" in choice, which they will try to take anyway.  Also, they have some of classes in their private libraries that have no prefix at all.  The masses are not the only ones who neglect the naming conventions.

Comment: @JodyHagins I only need to know that `SAObjects.framework` is provided by Apple and has nothing to do with the custom classes and frameworks I've added to my project... then I'm just going to rename my `SACalendar` class if it isn't necessary to do anything else, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be this: https://github.com/nopshusang/SACalendar

Yes, it is a problem.

However, you get this problem because you and many, many other developers do not read the Objective-C's and Cocoa's naming conventions. There are typically two mistakes:

- Prefixes with two letters are reserved for Apple. You are not allowed to use it. I really do not know, why do not respect this. This is the problem in your case.
- Prefixes does *not* denote a subject, but the origin of code. Therefore extending (subclass, category) a class from Cocoa (NS-Prefix) by a third-party developer does *not* have the prefix `NS`. But you see it everywhere.

I really do not know, why it is that difficult to accept that simple rules.

> Your own classes should use three letter prefixes. These might relate to a combination of your company name and your app name, or even a specific component within your app. As an example, if your company were called Whispering Oak, and you were developing a game called Zebra Surprise, you might choose WZS or WOZ as your class prefix.

Comment: Yes, that is the `SACalendar` class I added and I know, but I didn't know that other `SAObjects.framework`...

Answer (score 0):

As for what `SAObjects.framework` actually does, according to https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Siri, it contains "Resources for Siri objects".